# Que je l'en priasse

Tags: subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Dans *Voyage au bout de la nuit* :

> Alcide m’attendait. Il était un peu vexé. Ce fut cette invitation dont
> venait de m’honorer le lieutenant Grappa qui le décida sans doute aux
> grandes confidences. Et elles étaient salées les confidences. Il me
> fit sans **que je l’en priasse**, de Grappa, un portrait express au caca
> fumant.

Il m'est encore difficile de comprendre l'usage du subjonctif imparfait. Pourquoi l'auteur a écrit ici *que je l'en priasse* et non *que je l'en eusse prié* ?

Comment: Peut-être pour le plaisir rare de marier l'imparfait du subjonctif et le caca fumant...

Comment: Oui, je vois ça, merci. Mais à part ça, je n'arrive pas à visualiser l'imparfait du subjonctif

Comment: Cet imparfait n'est pas unique: *Il m’avait chargé, sans que je l’en priasse, de l’impression de ses Paroles d'un croyant.* Sainte-Beuve, *Mes Poisons*, 1926 (posthume) mais il faut plutôt voir la phrase comme une grosse plaisanterie transgressive.

Comment: Le contraste comique entre le début de la phrase, très académique, et la fin avec sa métaphore triviale, est-il possible uniquement avec l'imparfait du subjonctif ?

Comment: Il est plus fort avec *que je l'en priasse* qu'avec *que je l'en eusse prié*.

Answer (score 2):

Céline utilise l'imparfait  parce qu'il respecte probablement la concordance des temps, et considère que l'action de prier est quasiment simultanée à l'action de faire un portrait ; comme cette dernière action prend place dans le passé (fit), un imparfait convient. Il aurait pu utiliser le plus que parfait (eusse prié), et il aurait alors signifié que l'action de prier était—ce qui, strictement, devrait être le cas**—antérieure à celle de faire le portrait.

[image]
[Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-56184.php)

La référence ci-dessous donne une notion plus complète et des exemples supplémentaires.

[image]

[Le subjonctif et la concordance des temps - Sillages.info](http://www.sillages.info/flot/grammaire/sequence39_web_gen_auroraW/co/03_05_concordance_temps.html)

<sub>**Note 1** Il est moins que certain que l'effet comique, si on peut en voir un, ait été intentionnel ; dans cette œuvre même, Céline emploie l'imparfait du subjonctif et le plus que parfait assez souvent (au moins une soixantaine de subjonctifs en tout) ;

**imparfait** appliquasse (1), demeurassent (1), précisassent (1), vexassent (1), fusse (1), fussent (8), fissent (1), prisse (3), sacrifiât (1), expédiât (1), donnât (1), échappât (1), existât (1), menaçât (1), engueulât (1), bottât (1), s'agenouillât (1), considérât (1), apparusse (1), eût (2), fût (4), prît (2), reprît (1),  comprît (1), entendît (1), fît (1),</sub> 
<sub>**plus que parfait** eussent laissé (1), eussent été menacées (1), eussent eu (1), eussent été (1), eussent fait jurer (1), eusse pris (1), eussent ravi (1), eusse salué (1), eussions fini (1), eussent reçue (1), eussent cuisiné (1),  eussent propagées (1), eusse agi (1), eussent attiré (1), eusse préféré (1), eût été (4), se fût agi (2), eût manqué (1), eût ramassé (1), eût adoré (1), eût parlé (1), eût fallu (1),</sub>